# Python: Writing a pandas pivot table to an excel template

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

So I’ve been following this site for a while in relation to my knowledge base on Python. Decided to throw myself in the deep end with my first question, so hoping someone will be able to assist me.

**I currently have the following problem:**
Trying to print out a Pandas Pivot table into a pre-defined excel template, say from cell C5

**Code is below and table I load through CSV is also there**

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.compat import range
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
import pandas as pd

pnl_lst = pd.read_csv('data_test.csv', index_col=0)
pnl_lst = pd.DataFrame(pnl_lst, columns=['Fruit_Veg', 'Item', 'AmountSold','AmountRotten','#ofpickers'])
pnl_lst = pnl_lst.groupby('Fruit_Veg').apply(lambda x: x.pivot_table(index=['Item'],aggfunc='sum',margins=True,margins_name='Total'))
print(pnl_lst)
```

**Input table via data_test.csv**

|  | Fruit_Veg | Item | AmountSold | AmountRotten | #ofpickers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fruit | Apple | 0.907502 | 0.176108 | 0.365398 |
| 2 | Veg | Carrot | 0.707491 | 0.644805 | 0.375513 |
| 3 | Fruit | Pear | 0.898554 | 0.724919 | 0.338557 |
| 4 | Fruit | Raspberry | 0.284849 | 0.023705 | 0.80169 |
| 5 | Veg | Potato | 0.205464 | 0.682219 | 0.834467 |
| 6 | Veg | Aubergine | 0.644248 | 0.531195 | 0.970782 |

**Generated output (table has gone strange, but Fruit and Veg in the first column are merged cells):**

| Fruit_Veg | Item | #ofpickers | AmountRotten | AmountSold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fruit | Apple | 0.365398283 | 0.176107564 | 0.907502485 |
|  | Pear | 0.338556856 | 0.724919365 | 0.898554328 |
|  | Raspberry | 0.801690277 | 0.02370525 | 0.284848945 |
|  | Total | 1.505645416 | 0.924732179 | 2.090905758 |
| Veg | Aubergine | 0.970782439 | 0.531195328 | 0.644248183 |
|  | Carrot | 0.375513124 | 0.644804957 | 0.707491361 |
|  | Potato | 0.834466661 | 0.682219111 | 0.20546385 |
|  | Total | 2.180762224 | 1.858219396 | 1.557203394 |

**Attempted ideas (with no luck sadly):**

- I can print a pandas pivot table using XlsxWriter, but that’s writes to a separate excel file, not a template as I need it;
- Used Openpyxl to write the pivot table to an excel template, but no luck there as the formatting went all wrong and it couldn’t convert the pivot table into something readable which the module then writes;
- Tried replicating my pivot table using the pandas GroupBy function. I couldn’t quite figure out how to get the Totals to appear under each Fruit_Veg section as per the above output.

Does anyone have any sensible ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you do not want the cells to be merged, you can try specifying in the groupby operation by using the 'as_index' arg. ie;
groupby('Fruit_Veg',as_index=False)

Comment: @Boskosnitch thanks. I think the key issue here is not the merging, mainly the writing to an excel template. If you believe that the merged cells are the cause of this then i can give that a go also.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I write my output from a pandas dataframe to an excel template.
Please note that if data is already present in the cells where you are trying to write the dataframe, it will not be overwritten and the dataframe will be written to a new sheet which is my i have included a step to clear existing data from the template. I have not tried to write output on merged cells so that might throw an error.

Setup

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
file_path='Template.xlsx'
book=load_workbook(file_path)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
sheet_name="Template 1"
sheet=book[sheet_name]
```

Set first row and first column in the excel template where output is to be pasted.
If my output is to be pasted starting in cell N2, row_start will be 2 and col_start will be 14

```
row_start=2
col_start=14
```

Clear existing data in excel template

```
for c_idx, col in enumerate(df.columns,col_start):
    for r_idx in range(row_start,10001):
        sheet.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value="")
```

Write dataframe to excel template

```
rows=dataframe_to_rows(df,index=False)
for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows,row_start):
    for c_idx, col in enumerate(row,col_start):
        sheet.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=col)

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Syed. The issue here is that when i try and save it to the excel template, even using your code, the module doesn't detect columns and only throws back the data. So in my output i have provided, it throws only columns 3,4,5 (ignores Fruit_Veg and Item). Hence the data is shown, and collated, but there is no reference to that data.